# Is there any way to run a desktop 24/7 without monitor or VNC connection?

Tags: desktop

Nothing unusual about my system. I'm running a Raspberry Pi 3a+ with Raspberry Pi OS desktop, with
some tabs loading.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you don't have a monitor or VNC or forwarding X over SSH, What benefit are you getting from a headless box?

Comment: Just to clarify, I can run VNC / SSH however I often need to turn off the computer running
them. Since the Raspberry Pi is in a pretty awkward place, I would love to be able to disconnect and reconnect with the desktop not stopping whilst I was gone.

Comment: take a look at tmux it allows you to disconnect from the server and reconnect later.

Comment: what does 24/7 have to do with running without monitor or VNC?

Comment: Thanks @SteveRobillard . Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Raspberry Pi running a Tor proxy, Transmission torrent demon, nzb demon, Samba file server (NAS), dlna server. I run it 24/7 and go in via ssh terminal maybe once every week, and VNC much less often. VNC desktop opens where it was last time, provided I didn't reboot the Pi.

To close a VNC session on the local machine, you close the VNC window. This disconnects from the VNC server but anything you left open in the VNC session continues to run as long as the VNC server is running. Windows left open in VNC will still be there if you later reconnect, even if that is from a different workstation.